# Identity Server 4 - Allowed Origins configured and origin is not allowed

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I have a SPA and API in the same project and I keep getting the following errors when I make a request to the API.

```
AllowedOrigins configured and origin http://localhost:5000 is not allowed
CorsPolicyService did not allow origin: http://localhost:5000
```

The path to the api is: `http://localhost:5000`. I made sure I have the origin specified in the `ClientCorsOrigins` table for the client and I also added a policy in my `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000")
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
```

I've checked the docs and configuration multiple times and I can't figure out why I'm having this issue when I have the origin specified in the ClientCorsOrigins table. I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: Have you called `app.UseCors("default");` before `UseMvc`, or `[EnableCors("default")]` on your controller?

Comment: Yes. I have `app.UseCors("default");` before `UseMvc` and `UseAuthentication`.

Comment: well, could you then collect the sequence of http requests producing the error? must be something pretty simple... you say, API is at the same origin that MVC, so they can actually share the auth cookie and avoid the ajax redirect to idp at all...

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a row/record into [dbo].[ClientCorsOrigin] table with your ClientId and Origin.

CorsPolicyProvider.cs has a check in line [#62](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/Hosting/CorsPolicyProvider.cs#L62):

```
if (await corsPolicyService.IsOriginAllowedAsync(origin))
```

when it returns *false*, you have your "*CorsPolicyService did not allow origin: http://localhost:5000*" message in line [#69](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/Hosting/CorsPolicyProvider.cs#L69).

I assume, you are using IdentityServer4.EntityFramework. Here is the IsOriginAllowedAsync method from CorsPolicyService.cs located in IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Services namespace:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether origin is allowed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="origin">The origin.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task<bool> IsOriginAllowedAsync(string origin)
    {
        // doing this here and not in the ctor because: https://github.com/aspnet/CORS/issues/105
        var dbContext = _context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IConfigurationDbContext>();

        var origins = dbContext.Clients.SelectMany(x => x.AllowedCorsOrigins.Select(y => y.Origin)).ToList();

        var distinctOrigins = origins.Where(x => x != null).Distinct();

        var isAllowed = distinctOrigins.Contains(origin, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        _logger.LogDebug("Origin {origin} is allowed: {originAllowed}", origin, isAllowed);

        return Task.FromResult(isAllowed);
    }
```

Look at isAllowed, it is populated with data from AllowedCrossOrigins collection the content of which is stored in the [dbo].[ClientCorsOrigin] table.

So, please double check what you have in ClientCorsOrigin table.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem with my application.

I'm using `IdentityServer4`, and in `Startup.cs` in `ConfigureServices` I had to add `AllowedCorsOrigins` to the client of IdentityServer I was configuring (in my case inside `AddApiAuthorization()`).

This is my code:

```
         services
            .AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                // Clients
                var spaClient = ClientBuilder
                    .SPA("Name of your SPA Client")
                    .WithRedirectUri("https://...")
                    .WithLogoutRedirectUri("https://...")
                    .WithScopes("...")
                    .Build();
                spaClient.AllowedCorsOrigins = new[]
                {
                    "https://localhost:5300"
                };

                options.Clients.Add(spaClient);
            });
```

After adding that the log warning was gone!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
    services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService>((container) => {
            var logger = container.GetRequiredService<ILogger<DefaultCorsPolicyService>>();
            return new DefaultCorsPolicyService(logger)
            {
                 AllowAll = true
            };
        });
...
}
```